# python3: map list of sets to list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of sets like this:

```
A=[{1,2},{3,4},{1,5}]
```

I want to map `A` to a list of lists instead of list of sets like this:

```
A=[[1,2],[3,4],[1,5]]
```

can any body help me How can I do this?

Comment: Sets are unordered, lists maintain order. What order do you expect your lists to be in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

**Ex:**

```
>>> A=[{1,2},{3,4},{1,5}]
>>> print(list(map(list, A)))
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 5]]
```